# Visibility of ISS at extreme latitudes

Tags: iss

Is there a limit to the latitudes the ISS can be seen from (i.e. could it be seen at the North or South poles)?

Comment: I mean I live in south NZ, and I've tracked the ISS across the sky...

Answer (score 13):

The ISS's orbit is inclined 51.64°, so that's the most extreme latitude where you can see it directly overhead at the right time.

Visibility requires that the ISS rises above the visible horizon. For let's say five degrees that limits visibility to between about 66° N and S. Further north or south there's no way to see the ISS from the Earth's surface as it always stays below the horizon.

**Calculation**

At the extreme, you are looking along the horizon at zero elevation, tangent to the surface.  When that happens, the ISS, you, and the Earth's center form a right triangle, with the right angle on your position. The adjacent side is the Earth's radius, and the hypotenuse is the ISS's distance from the Earth's center (radius+altitude). adjacent side/hypotenuse = cosine of the angle between your Earth-centered position vector and the ISS's. The Earth's radius is 6370 km, the ISS's altitude 416 km:

*arccos(6370/(6370+416)) ≈ 20°*

so your position must be within some combination of latitude and longitude that puts you within that cone centered on the ISS's position.  If you want to take account of looking slightly above the horizon, the math gets harder, because it isn't a right triangle anymore.

Comment: I'm having difficulty finding the actual answer to either "Is there a limit to the latitudes the ISS can be seen from"? or "i.e. could it be seen at the North or South poles?" Is there a limit (Yes/No)? Could it be seen at the North or South poles (Yes/No)? Note that the elevation of the South pole is about 2,835 m above (presumably) [the WGS84 ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS_84) but that's only 6,356,752 m from the center of the Earth. Viewing from the North pole would not have that extra 2,835 m to work with.

Comment: This answer calculates that the limit at extreme would be 51.6° + 20° = 71N or 71S latitude. So no, there is no hope of seeing ISS from north or south pole, and even at 71° latitude it would require a locally high observing point.